# Creating empty ag-grid table

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

Does anyone tried to create empty ag-grid table and then e.g add values when double-clicked on it?

I want to define number of columns and rows in editor and when saving it create empty ag grid. Is that possible?

Comment: Hi , did you find any answer or solution for your question other than mentioned below. by @Viqas ?

Comment: @SumitPatel I ended up initializing dinamically initializing an object with empty values based on rows/columns number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your ag-grid as usual, then pass in your data with empty values, e.g.

```
this.gridOptions.rowData = [
            {id: '', value: ''},
            {id: '', value: ''},
            {id: '', value: ''},
            {id: '', value: ''},
            {id: '', value: ''}
        ]
```

All fields will be empty, then you can let the user edit the fields.

Take a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-e9ejg7) StackBlitz example.